# readonly for root ( -i flag disabled )

Tags: linux, root, readonly

A friend set me a readonly bad wallpaper on ubuntu gnome. I want to change it.

I found the file i have to modify : `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/00_default-wallpaper`

but when I open it with `vim`, I can see at the bottom : `[readonly]`
and when I attempt to modify it, it writes :

```
E212 : Can’t open file for writing
```

I'm logged as root and have already disabled the immutable flag with chattr.

Answer (score -1):

1) log in as root

2) cd to  /etc/dconf/db/local.d/

3) issue the command 'chmod 777 00_default-wallpaper'

4) use wallpaper

Comment: I have already done that

Comment: it prints : operation not permitted